# CPU usage is high in Chrome when using Node.TransitionTo method of KineticJS

Tags: transition, kineticjs

I make an animation sample to compare the CPU/Memory usage between KineticJS and Move.js(CSS3).
In animation, I used Node.TransitionTo method. I found that the CPU/Memory usage is extremely high i Chrome 22+. So I'd like to ask if there is any way to reduce the cost of CPU/Memory.